# How to emulate USB pendrive with Arduino + micro SD card + WiFi shield?

Tags: arduino, wifi, usb-drive

I have RGB panel board, coming with USB socket.
I can edit graphics on PC, save  file to USB pendrive.
When I insert USB pendrive into my RGB panel board, saved graphics file is read and graphics starts to be displayed live.

Since my RGB panel board is mounted overhead I would like to emulate USB pendrive with Arduino + micro SD card + WiFi shield, to keep Arduino always connected to USB socket as OTG
and update graphics file via WiFi upload from PC or smartphone.

There is WiFi SD card, coming with remote WiFi access functionality

There is WiFi Pendrive by SanDisk

https://absolutegizmos.com/sandisk-connect-wireless-stick-review-the-wifi-pendrive/

WiFi Pendrive by SanDisk is coming with on/off switch,  which is not easy to access if WiFi Pendrive is inserted intop RGB panel board installed overhead

Let me know which option can work for me or you have pretested to work in the past.

thank you

darius

Comment: it would be much simpler to write a PC program which sends the data to Arduino WiFiServer then to try to read what the Pendrive sends over WiFi

Comment: Thank you. Can Arduino WiFiServer replace USB pendrive inserted into USB socket in my RGB panel board ?  I need to remotely (over WiFi) upload one file only at a time to not remove USB pendrive from RGB panel board, insert into PC for graphics file load and insert into USB socket in RGB panel board back, over and over again.  In theory WiFi Pendrive should work, as described by SanDisk in a link provided above. Not sure how to operate remotely on/off switch on pendrive. WiFi Pendrives by SanDisk are not popular in Europe to get one for tests  today

Comment: the upload a file from PC to Arduino. you don't need to transfer a complete filesystem

Comment: exactly as is the case with Android tablet connected to PC running MS windows. But the problem is if the RGB panel board can read such file from Arduino via USB OTG, recognizing Arduino as USB Pendrive

Comment: then you need an Ardunio which can act as USB Mass Storage device

Comment: exactly , arduino + Wifi shield + micro SD card + libraries to emulate SD card as USB Mass Storage device  What comes next is OTG power supply problem since USB Pendrive gets power from USB socket. If you connect Arduino powered USB plug with RGB panel board's powered USB socket, voltages may not match. But I am sure, someone did it before to work.

Comment: I don't understand the concept of what you try to achieve? the Arduino should replace the WiFi pendrive? why?

Comment: If you install RGB panel board overhead you get restricted access to upload new graphics file via USB Pendrive. Only few RGB panel boards come with WiFi wireless access for file upload

Comment: and the WiFi pendrive doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: It's not clear from the WiFi Pendrive description by SanDisk, if my intended mode of operation is supported. Have no option to test it locally, so would prefer to fund Arduino emulator of USB Mass Storage to exactly fit my needs. 2.Option is to use 5m long usb cable to get easy access to pendrive  3.Option is to buy RGB display board with WiFi support enabled

Comment: so search for Arduino USB Mass Storage library

Comment: Thank you. A number of good web links from search engine : https://www.bing.com/search?q=Arduino+USB+Mass+Storage+library&go=Submit+Query&qs=ds&form=QBLH  I need to study

Comment: as far as I know they are only for the 32 bit MCUs, so check the compatibility of the library with hardware